# Need to assign the output block into different variables and echo only required variables

Tags: arrays, variables, vbscript

I had to extract some item details basically values from a webpage and display them.

The sample source of the webpage is

```html
<h2>Item Information</h2>

<dl>
    <dt>Item Domain</dt>
    <dd>xyx.domain.com</dd>

    <dt>Item IP address</dt>
    <dd>xxx.xxx.xx.x port 0000</dd>

    <!--
    <dt>Item Class</dt>
    <dd>Class 5.4.0</dd>
    -->

    <dt>Item Serial #</dt>
    <dd>9090909090</dd>

    <dt>Client Item IP</dt>
    <dd>yyy.yyy.yyy.yy</dd>

    <dt>Client Logged In As</dt>
    <dd>remo</dd>

    <dt>Item user is member of</dt>
    <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

I could get the necessary lines from the above input using below code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const csURL           = "http://itemdetails.inf/"            
Dim csFSpec : csFSpec = "C:\Desktop\new123.txt"

WScript.Quit useRegExp()

Function getURL(sURL)
    Dim oHTTP : Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    oHTTP.Open "GET", csURL, False
    oHTTP.Send
    If 200 = oHTTP.Status Then
        Dim goFS : Set goFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        goFS.CreateTextFile(csFSpec, 2).Write oHTTP.responseText
    Else
       WScript.Echo "URL Down"
    End If
End Function 

Function useRegExp()
    Dim oMT
    Dim sAl   : sAl       = getURL(csURL)
    Dim sAll  : sAll      = goFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec).ReadAll()
    Dim reCut : Set reCut = New RegExp
    reCut.Global  = True
    reCut.Pattern = "<dd>.+"
    Dim oMTS  : Set oMTS  = reCut.Execute(sAll)
    If oMTS.Count > 0 Then
        For Each oMT In oMTS
            WScript.Echo oMT
        Next
    Else
       WScript.Echo "No Matches"
    End If
    useRegExp = 0
End Function
```

And I'm getting the below output:

```html
<dd>xyx.domain.com</dd>
<dd>xxx.xxx.xx.x port 0000</dd>
<dd>Class 5.4.0</dd>
<dd>9090909090</dd>
<dd>yyy.yyy.yyy.yy</dd>
<dd>remo</dd>
<dd></dd>
```

Now I need to assign these in to different variable after trimming the `<dd>` &`</dd>` tags. For instance:

```
a=xyx.domain.com
b=xxx.xxx.xx.x port 0000
c=Class 5.4.0
d=9090909090
e=yyy.yyy.yyy.yy
f=remo
```

Such that I can echo only the necessary variables. Since I need to make this script into different versions and get different variables based on the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echoing the values right away put them into an array like this:

```
ReDim arr(-1)
Dim oMTS  : Set oMTS  = reCut.Execute(sAll)
If oMTS.Count > 0 Then
    For Each oMT In oMTS
        ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr)+1)
        arr(UBound(arr)) = oMT
    Next
End If
```

Then you can output them by index:

```
If UBound(arr) = -1 Then
    WScript.Echo "No Matches"
Else
    'echo 2nd and 4th element
    WScript.Echo arr(1)
    WScript.Echo arr(3)
End If
```

Creating dynamically named variables on the fly is not trivial in VBScript, so you're usually better off using an array or a dictionary.

Comment: It was a perfect one... I had to include the couple of line for trimming the  <dd> & </dd> tags
Dim x : x = Split(oMT,"<")(1)
Dim y : y = Split(x,">")(1)